# Assign drupal tags automatically

Tags: php, drupal

This seems very intuitive but I can't seem to get it.

When creating a new article, how do I assign tags automatically based on the authors role? I've tried various modules, but none of them worked in this way that I need.

Is the best way to go into the module file, check the current role of the author, then set the value of the tag? Im not that familiar with drupal, so I'm not entirely sure where/how to do that and if that's the best way.

Thanks for any input!

Answer (score 1):

There are various options for this. The ones that I am most familiar with are:

1. [Open Calais](http://drupal.org/project/opencalais/): Developed by Thomson Reuters, this module/service can assign several configurable tags to a content entity ranging from subject areas and topics to names of people and locations. Very comprehensive.
2. [Rules tagging](http://drupal.org/project/rules_autotag): A more light weight approach, but not as powerful as Calais.
3. [Text mining API](http://drupal.org/project/textmining_api): This one relies on the Ouch project for auto tagging.

There is a very [good article on Drupal.org](http://groups.drupal.org/node/38290/) giving a comparison of such modules. Maybe that should be your starting point.

Comment: Rules tagging looks promising, but I don't see how i can assign tags based on user role? For instance, if an author is in the role "sports" I want the field_tags field to automatically add "sports" as a tag to that article. That doesn't seem possible? Is that something that works with the Rules module?

Comment: Definitely. The Rules module will be perfect for the scenario you describe. Muck around a bit with it and you'll be able to figure it out.